# Calculus Midterm Question.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm studying for my calc midterm right now, and I was finding the limit of the question:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}{\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{2x}}{x-2}}\tag{1}$$

When I was trying to solve it I came up with this:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}{\frac{\sqrt{x+2}^{2} - \sqrt{2x}^{2}}{x-2(\sqrt{x-2}+ \sqrt{2x})}}\tag{2}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}{\frac{x + 2 - 2x}{x-2(\sqrt{x+2}+ \sqrt{2x})}}\tag{3}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}{\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x}}}\tag{4}$$

However, the solution is this: [Solution](http://gyazo.com/e6fde3c815021770df00314442245ac4.png)

I'm not understanding what happens to that $-2x.$

Comment: Use `\lim` and `\frac` rather that `\over`.

Comment: I have edited the first part of your post to use `\lim` and `\frac`. Please use that example to format the rest of your post. If you haven't read it already, I advise you to read through [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on formatting math with MathJax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is your move from line $(3)$ to line $(4)$. Those two expressions are not equal.

Multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of $\;\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{2x}}{ x-2}\;$ gives us:

$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{2x}}{x-2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x}}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x}}
& = \frac{x+2 - 2x}{(x- 2)(\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x)}} \tag{a}\\ \\
& = \frac{-(x-2)}{(x- 2)(\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x)}} \tag{b} \\ \\
& = \frac{-1}{(\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x)}}\tag{c}\\ \\ 
\end{align}
$$

Now evaluate your $\displaystyle \;\;\lim_{x\to 2} \; \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x}}$.

---

Note that the $x + 2 - 2x = -x + 2 = -(x-2)$, and so we are able to cancel the factor $(x - 2)$ from both numerator and denominator.

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{2x}}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to 2}\;\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x)}} = \frac{-1}{4}$$

Comment: I understand everything you did up until: x+2-2x = -(x-2), wouldn't you just cancel the x+2 with the denominators x-2?

Comment: No the numerator is not x+2: and even if it were, it would not cancel with (x - 2). Note that $x + 2 - 2x = x - 2x + 2 = -x + 2 = -(x-2)$  Now we can cancel the  factor $(x - 2)$ from the numerator and denominator, leaving only $-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I understand now.

Comment: The denominator is x-2 multiplied by the term with roots, and it should come under both x+2 and -2x.

Comment: Totally forgot about accepting it, just did, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: It is nice when ops are thoughtful too! +1

Answer (score 0):

L' Hospital's rule can only be applied to a term which goes to $\frac{0}{0}$ (or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, which is not applicable here.) Here, the term,

$\frac{x + 2 - 2x}{x-2}$, goes to $\frac{0}{0}$ as $x$ tends to $2$. So the rule applies to this term. You are making a mistake by applying the rule to $\frac{x+2}{x-2}$. Here only the denominator goes to zero, as $x$ tends to $2$, not the numerator.

In any case, I don't see, how you can split up the function in that manner.